# how to replace a word first occurrence from string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a input

> Input :- Or Like %Gifts%Or Like % Packaging%
>   
>  Expected Output:-
>   %Gifts%Or Like % Packaging%

How to achieve this in sql

Comment: So what you want is replace the first `Or like` ?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want ? replace 1st occurance of the word `Or Like` ?

```
declare @str    varchar(100) = 'Or Like %Gifts%Or Like % Packaging%',
        @word   varchar(10)  = 'Or Like'

select  [output]    = case  when charindex(@word, @str) > 0
                            then stuff(@str, charindex(@word, @str), len(@word), '')
                            else @str
                            end
```

You may use charindex() to find the 1st occurance of the string
Then remove that string by stuff() it with empty string